# "An unknown error occurred" when signing into iMessage account with Apple ID on macOS

Tags: macos, icloud

The `Messages` app wasn't longer able to send messages saying `Not Delivered`, so I signed out. When signing back in I see this:

[image]

Note that Apple *does* see the login: I get an email saying so

[image]

The information in that email is correct, so then why the error message?  Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to have the same error on my device once.

In my case it helped resetting the NVRAM, which is one of the recommendations in [Apple's documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204408).

> **Reset NVRAM or PRAM on your Mac**
>
> ⌥ + ⌘ + P + R
>
> Shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold these four keys together: Option, Command, P, and R. You can release the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac might appear to restart.
>
> `https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063`

Comment: in my case it ended up getting cleaned up by a full reboot but without the need for nvram. But i'll award.

Comment: Note that resetting the NVRAM **only applies for an Intel-based Mac, NOT for Apple silicon**. See the [Reset NVRAM on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) help page.