# "An unknown error occurred" when signing into Messages with Apple ID on an Apple Silicon Mac

Tags: mac, messages, apple-id, apple-silicon

I am currently unable to sign in to Messages with my Apple ID on my Mac (version numbers included at the end). The error messages that comes up is the not-so-helpful, "An unknown error as occurred". I have followed the instructions on the [If you can't sign in to your iMessage account or FaceTime on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204408) page. As of 2023-08-21 the instructions are the following:

1. ✅ Check your internet connection
2. ✅ Check for a service outage
3. ✅ Check your Date & Time settings
4. ✅ Make sure that your software is up to date
5. Check your Apple ID

   1. ✅ To make sure that your Apple ID and password are correct, go to the Apple ID account page and sign in with the same Apple ID that you're using with Messages and FaceTime.
   2. Messages: Choose Messages > Settings (or Preferences), then click Sign Out. Sign in again with the same Apple ID you used on the Apple ID account page.

      **I can't sign out. I can click the button, but it stays stuck loading.**
6. ✅ Reset NVRAM

   Does not apply for Apple Silicon. See the [Reset NVRAM on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) help page.

   > The steps to reset NVRAM don't apply to Mac computers with Apple silicon, and aren't needed on those computers.
7. ✅ Check for third-party software

   **I don't think I have software that will impact this connection issue, but I am not sure.** The only VPN I have installed is not turned on, and checking System Preferences > Profiles shows no installed profiles.

---

This question is *very similar to, but differs from* ["An unknown error occurred" when signing into iMessage account with Apple ID on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373511/an-unknown-error-occurred-when-signing-into-imessage-account-with-apple-id-on) *in a few key ways.*

1. I do not receive an email about the log-in attempt.
2. Resetting NVRAM does not apply because my Mac uses Apple Silicon.
3. The person asking the question seemed to be able to log out successfully. I get stuck when trying to log out.

---

Version numbers:

- 2022 M2 MacBook Air
- macOS Ventura 13.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More things to try… this should be known as the iCloud hokey cokey.

- Reboot
- Sign out of everything, Messages, Music, FaceTime, App Store
- Reboot again
- Try to sign back in

Answer (score 1):

Just opening the Facetime app fixed the issue for me, iMessage just started to work.

Comment: Logging in in FaceTime fixed this for me, thank you